# How can i show doughnut chart first instead of clicking the labels?

Tags: angular, charts

**html**

```
           <div class="m-widget14">
           <div class="m-widget14__header">
              <h3 class="m-widget14__title">
              Insurance details
             </h3>
            <span class="m-widget14__desc">

          </span>
        </div>
       <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:50vw; displablock">
<canvas 

 baseChart
        [data]="doughnutChartData1"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  [colors]="chartColors"
  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"

  ></canvas>
```

**component class**

[image comes when page opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYjIs.png)

```
              ngOnInit() {
          this.insuranceDashSer.getTotalInsurance().subscribe(res=>
            {

             this.body=res;

   this.body.forEach(element => {

     this.doughnutChartData.push(element);
     console.log(" Array values"+JSON.stringify(this.doughnutChartData));
  });

  // this.doughnutChartData.slice(0);
  this.doughnutChartData1[0]=this.doughnutChartData[1];
  this.doughnutChartData1[1]=this.doughnutChartData[2];
  this.doughnutChartData1[2]=this.doughnutChartData[3];
  this.doughnutChartData1[3]=this.doughnutChartData[4];
  console.log(this.doughnutChartData1);
});
```

}

i tried a lots of times, i don't know why i am getting this output when the page load,but when i click on the label, the chart will be displayed

Comment: looks like first time page displayed - you have no data to show (that is why only vertical line is seen). But is it really problem? If you have no data - why not to show that to user?

Comment: I have called the function in ng init So there is data , when i click on any of the label then only chart will display.?so i want to get the chart when page is open

Comment: where is a data but i guess - the data is [] (empty array)

Comment: No the array is not empty, i get output as  array with values,but i dont know why the labels are strike while open the page

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
public doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [550, 450, 100],
    [50, 220, 120],
    [250, 130, 70],//Can add multiple data points here
  ];
```

you can append the multiple values for the doughnutChartData

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart 
    [data]="doughnutChartData"
    [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
    [chartType]="doughnutChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Stackblitz working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-angular2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)